# Android MediaSessionCompat.setPlaybackState doesn't notify on position changes

Tags: android

I'm curious if anyone has ran into this problem or has any suggestions. I'm writing a media player in which I'm utilizing the MediaSessionCompat API. Every so often I determine the current position of the playing media and raise a change event. I re-set the playback state as seen below. However, since the `STATE_PLAYING` state does not change, Android does not raise the notification that the position value changed. In particular, when I have a Bluetooth device connected that displays the current position, the Bluetooth device only receives the position when the state changes from `STATE_PLAYING` to `STATE_PAUSED`, or vice versa. See code below:

```
public void setup() {
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(context, Schema.TAG, component, pendingIntent);
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
    updatePlaybackState();
}

public void updatePlaybackState() {
    int state = isPlaying() ? PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING : PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED;
    int ms = getCurrentPosition();
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setState(state, ms, 1f)
            .build());
}
```

In this example, I call `updatePlaybackState` when the current position changes. If I change the `updatePlaybackState` method as follows, then it works as expected; though, I'm not sure if I should be doing it this way.

```
public void updatePlaybackState() {
    int state = isPlaying() ? PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING : PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED;
    int ms = getCurrentPosition();
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE, ms, 1f)
            .build());
    mediaSession.setPlaybackState(new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setState(state, ms, 1f)
            .build());
}
```

As you can see, I set the state to `STATE_NONE` and then I re-set the state back to `STATE_PLAYING` to cause Android to notice that the state changed, which re-publishes the current position to the connected Bluetooth device.

Comment: How do you detect the position changes? Can't find that info in documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

How does the bluetooth device read the position? I'm assuming some code constantly monitors the playbackstate to get the current position?

To prevent you from constantly having to update the `PlaybackState`, the playback state contains the necessary values to compute the approximate current position of the stream.

When setting the playbackState, you provide values such as speed, current position and the update time.

`PlaybackState.Builder.setState(int state, long position, float playbackSpeed, long updateTime)`

Given the assertion that unless the playback state changes and it is currently playing, you can calculate the currentPosition from the lastUpdate time, speed and the previousPosition.

```
long timeDelta = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastPlaybackState.getLastPositionUpdateTime();
long currentPosition = (int) timeDelta * lastPlaybackState.getPlaybackSpeed();
```

You can take a look at how uAmp does this in [FullScreenPlayerActivity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/f3154af7ac972ee9b7b1fd32ca3c935e02268a18/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/ui/FullScreenPlayerActivity.java#L398-L413). The specific method is `updateProgress(..)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The bluetooth device I'm using is the stereo in my car. I'm assuming it only receives the current position from the Android device if the Android device tells it what the current position is. I have a thread that runs every 500ms, similar to the `scheduleSeekbarUpdate() `method in the code you posted for uAmp. I, however, ask the MediaPlayer for the `getCurrentPosition()` and then am trying to broadcast that value to the bluetooth device.

Comment: Actually `scheduleSeekbarUpdate()` simply calculates the elapsed time from last playbackState change and sets the value on the progress bar. That way it does not have to make an explicit call to get the current position. If the state changes, then the MediaController.Callback method is triggered which results in an updated playbackState and thus an update of the seek bar.

Comment: Right, my problem is not determining the latest position of the seek bar. My problem is notifying the bluetooth device of the latest position.

Comment: Link to the `updateProgress` method mentioned above (for lazy folks like me) https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/ui/FullScreenPlayerActivity.java#L398